# How to save a default entity property Collection value to database using Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, orm

I have an entity, that has a collection field:

```
@Type(type = "jsonb")
@ColumnDefault("'[\"V1\",\"V2\"]'")
@Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb", nullable = false)
private Collection<MyEnum> myCollection = new ArrayList<>();
```

If "myCollection" field will be null and Hibernate will try to save it into DB, it will fall, because it will try to insert null value.
How can I configure Hibernate, if this value is null in this entity, it should generate "DEFAULT" value in insert command? Why it doesn't see `nullable = false` in @Column?

Comment: nullable = false does not automatically translate to Hibernate inserting a default value when the Java entity field is null. Hibernate will, by default, try to insert null, leading to a violation of the not-null constraint in your database if the entity field is null. The most straightforward way is to ensure that myCollection is never null when the entity is saved. You're already initializing it with new ArrayList<>(), so as long as you don't set it to null explicitly, it should always have a non-null value (an empty list in the worst case).

Comment: You need [`@DynamicInsert`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#schema-generation-column-default-value) decorator on the entity. Otherwise it does set up the column `default`, but inserts from hibernate still attempt to slide a *`null`* in there, overriding it.

Answer (score 1):

You need [`@DynamicInsert`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#schema-generation-column-default-value) decorator on the entity. Otherwise it does set up the column `default`, but inserts from hibernate still attempt to slide a *`null`* in there, overriding it:

> The entity is annotated with the `@DynamicInsert` annotation so that the `INSERT` statement does not include the entity attribute that have not been set.

```java
@Entity(name = "Person")
@DynamicInsert//--------------here
public static class Person {
    //...
    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @ColumnDefault("'[\"V1\",\"V2\"]'")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb", nullable = false)
    private Collection<MyEnum> myCollection = new ArrayList<>();
    //...
}
```

Comment: If I will put this annotation, Hibernate will generate 'DEFAULT' value to all fields that are null and has @Column(nullable = false)?

Comment: @programmer That, or it'll skip them, which has the same effect: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/o-2pj2w4)